# Firebase Notifications triggers wrong delegate on iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-notifications

I am using `Firebase` to set up push notifications on iOS 10.
My app is receiving remote messages while in the foreground, but not in the background. Background messages are only received on opening the app.

Somehow all push notifications are received through `applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:`, Firebase's data message delegate, while in fact I never send a data payload.

I exactly implemented `AppDelegate` as mentioned in the tutorial on Firebase's website, I set the APNS tokens myself and the certificates are all in the right place. Also, my payload is sent with priority 'high' and content-available.

Anyone got an idea why iOS 10's native remote message handler (`userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:`) is never called instead?

Thanks a lot! (Have been debugging this for two days straight now...)

Comment: if you put notification key in your message then app will receive notification and will work fine  like this  {\"notification\":{\"body\":\"iOS Notification\"}, \"priority":\"high"}"

Comment: I already did that. Still goes to the data message delegate though

Comment: Did you have any luck?  Have run into this issue after upgrading to XCode 8.2. Was working fine before.

Comment: Make sure you don't implement the data delegate, and also be sure to remove any Cloud Messaging code, such as `connectToFcm` and the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into this same problem.

I resolved it by adding the following text to sender:

```
"notification":{"body":""}}
```

Don't set the Firebase delegate and just handle it in the old method

```
didReceiveRemoteNotification
```

Comment: This worked for me too. Generally, don't include any of the Firebase Cloud Messaging API apart from what's strictly needed for Notifications. My code also broke everytime I called `connectToFcm` and the like.

Answer (score 0):

look into [firebase method swizzling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#token-swizzle-disabled)

> The FCM SDK performs method swizzling in two key areas: mapping your
>   APNs token to the FCM registration token and capturing analytics data
>   during downstream message callback handling. Developers who prefer not
>   to use swizzling can disable it by adding the flag
>   FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled in the app’s Info.plist file and
>   setting it to NO (boolean value). Relevant areas of the guides provide
>   code examples, both with and without method swizzling enabled.